# Deploy reactjs application on the container instance

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

I am very new  to this Containers, so I am unable to deploy the application on the Container instance .
I tried below steps but i could not resolve the issue. Please help me out of this. Thanks in advance

steps:

1.I have created the Reactjs build.

2.Created the docker image and Create the container registry and pushed it into docker container instance.

my Docker file is :

```
FROM nginx: version 
copy /build/user/share/nginx/html
```

I have created the docker image and build that image and successfully created the docker image
I have created the container rgistry and when I trying to push the docker image to container instance after that i am not able to access the application using web.

```
docker build -t image_name
```

Can anyone help me that how to access the application through UI

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below results***

***I have created and build the npm using below command***

```
npm run build
```

[image]

***I have created example docker file and run the file***

```
#docker build -t image_name
FROM node:16.13.1-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node/_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install react-scripts -g --silent
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx","-g","daemon off"]
```

***I have created the container registry***

[image]

***Enabled the access to to push the image to container registry***

[image]

***I have logged into the container registry using login server credentials***

```
docker login server_name
username:XXXX
password:XXXXX
```

[image]

***I have tagged and pushed the image into container registry***

```
docker tag image_name login-server/image
docker push login-server/image_name
```

[image]

***I have created the container instances to deploy the container image***

*While creating in Networking i have given the DNS label and created*

[image]

***By using FQDN link I can able to access the image through UI***

[image]